# Automatic box uncheck in posting after an hour or more

Tags: wordpress, function, checkbox

I have a post that when I want to publish it on the homepage so it's a stick post via meta_tag.

But to remove this post from meta_key I need to go back to the post to manually wet the checkbox.

Is there any other way for this checkbox to go off automatically after it's done an hour through function?

Example I have the 'News-latest' checkbox ID and meta_key => 'The latest news' after one hour of checkbox or 'news-latest' metakey to be automatically uncheck by the post in metakey.

[image: Checkbox]